# Bash: Address (kill) terminal based on its title?

Tags: bash, terminal, kill

I have several terminals getting opened from a "base" one using `gnome-terminal` with specific titles using `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"'` and executing stuff.

Is it possible to address these terminals later on based on their title (for example executing commands in particular ones) or storing their "ID" from the "mother" terminal or at least for killing certain ones of them when dont need them any more?

Regarding the killing I can at least assume that their number in `top` would be ascending by the order in which they were opened but this is not really bullet-proof as there may be another terminal opened on the way or even in between.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. The `PROMPT_COMMAND` is for the bash running under the gnome-terminal.

The best you can do is use the PID of the terminal:

```
gnome-terminal &
first_teminal=$!
gnome-terminal &
second_terminal=$!
```

etcetera and kill them

```
kill $first_terminal
```

Comment: I dont get this, sorry. This **gnome-terminal** opens one, this other line **first_teminal=$!** doesnt seemingly do anything and when typed kill $first_terminal I only get **kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]**